# Bootstrap Nav Collapsing to Two Lines (Best Practices)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

A site I'm working on is using bootstrap and right now, when collapsing the window, the nav breaks to 2 lines at about 992px wide. I'm curious as to what the best practice is for avoiding this. I've read a lot on the topic but everyone seems to have their own opinion as to what is best. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Live site is here: http://vinylmeplease.com/

Comment: I think it is really a case of working with media queries to control the layout at a given breakpoint. Whether it means hiding elements or moving them to different locations it really is your call.  As you know you are repeating the "request invite" button twice...so perhaps to get the menu to line up nicely it is just a case of hiding it for this size? Personally I don't necessarily think there is a "wrong" way to do it (in this context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just hide the "Request Invite" button at that specific media-query width. It's repeated below anyways. Then you can have the nav links line up nicely within one line. This is just my best opinion :)

Example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {

     nav.main-nav ul li .btn {
         display:none;
     }

}
```